# Как индексировать массив пользовательского типа?

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов, index

Задание: написать operator для сложения множеств.
Есть пользовательский класс целых чисел `Znumbers`.
Нужно выполнить объединение множеств.

Выполняю в порядке:

1. ввести с клавиатуры длину 2-х массивов
2. заполнить массивы
3. объединить массивы

Я не понимаю, как в операторе `public static Znumbers operator +()` индексировать `Array1` и `Array2`, чтобы не вылетала ошибка

> CS021 Не удаётся применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа Znumbers

```cs
public class Znumbers
{
    public int[] Array;

    public Znumbers(int[] array) // конструктор                           
    { Array = array; }


    public int Length
    { get { return Array.Length; } }

    int length; 


    // МЕТОД ДЛЯ ЗАПОЛНЕНИЯ МАССИВОВ И УКАЗАНИЯ КОЛ-ВА ЭЛ-ОВ
    public void FillArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the length of the array");
        length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // ЗАПОЛНЯЕМ Array
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }


    //  ВЫВОДИМ НА ЭКРАН МАССИВ
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Array[i]);
        }
    }

       // ОБЪЕДИНЕНИЕ МНОЖЕСТВ

    public static Znumbers operator +(Znumbers Array1, Znumbers Array2)

    {

        //???

        int[] Array3 = new int[Array1.Length + Array2.Length];

        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Array1.Length; i++, j++)
            Array3[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Array1[i]);  // 

        for (int i = Array1.Length; i < Array2.Length; i++, j++)
            Array3[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Array2[i]);

        return new Znumbers(Array3);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        int[] b = new int[10];
  
        Znumbers massiv1 = new Znumbers(a);
        Znumbers massiv2 = new Znumbers(b);
        Znumbers massiv3;
        massiv3 = massiv1 + massiv2;  // объединение массивов
        Console.WriteLine(massiv3);
       
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Индексирование типа такого:

```cs
int [] array = { 1,2,3 }
public int this[int number]
{ 
    get
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++}
            return j;
    }
    return -1
}
```

Не понимаю, как индексировать пользовательский тип данных (`Znumbers`) с заполнением массива с клавиатуры.

Направьте, пожалуйста, в какую сторону хотя бы смотреть.

Comment: оператор индексирования перегружать пробовали?

Comment: @tym32167, нет нужды. Поле `Array` и так доступно

Comment: индексатор не нужен, так как есть прямой доступ к полу `Array` с которым сразу все работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это элементарно. Есть 2 варианта:

**Первый**: просто образатся по индексу к полю `Array`:

```
...Array1.Array[i]...
```

**Второй**: добавить возможность индексирования классу `Znumbers`:

```
public class Znumbers
{
    ...

    public int this[int i]
    {
        get { return Array[i]; }
        set { Array[i] = value; }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!